# When trying to add a space back into a tokenized String, why are two spaces added into my output?

Tags: string, tokenize, stringbuilder

Beginner here. Sorry for the vague title but the code should put my question into perspective.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    String sentence = "hi. how are you! i'm just dandy.";
    String tokenSent;

    tokenSent = sentenceCapitalizer(sentence);

    System.out.println(tokenSent);
}

public static String sentenceCapitalizer(String theSentence)
{
    StringTokenizer strTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(theSentence, ".!", true);

    String token = null;
    String totalToken = "";
    String ch = "";

    while(strTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        token = strTokenizer.nextToken().trim();

        token = token.replace(token.charAt(0), Character.toUpperCase(token.charAt(0)));

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(token);
        str.append(" ");

        totalToken += str;

    }

    return totalToken; 
}
```

OUTPUT AS IS: Hi . How are you ! I'm just dandy .

I was able to capitalize the first letter of each sentence but I'm wanting the output to keep the same format as the original String. The problem is that it puts a space before and after the ending punctuation. Is there any way to fix this problem using only a StringBuilder and/or StringTokenizer? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this.

```
String delim = ".!";
StringTokenizer strTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(theSentence, delim, true);
```

Then,

```
if(delim.contains(token))
    str.append(" ");
```

Comment: Makes so much sense. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `new StringTokenizer(theSentence, ".!", true)` ,`true` enables to return delimiter characters also as next token. Since you appending a space to each token, it is normal to get that output.

You can check if the token is a delimiter character, if so, you add the space.

```
if(token.length() == 1 &&
   delims.indexOf(token.charAt(0)) != -1)
 str.append(" "); //we just hit the delim char, add space
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. The problem is that when we don't add the space, the sentences run together, this being the output: Hi.How are you!I'm just dandy.